# Better way for boolean methods rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can we have a boolean function so that we are not required to use '!'
Suppose I have a boolean function has_done_something? and
I want to do another action only if user has not done that action
so I could do it by !has_done_something? or by writing the function has_not_done_something? .
just guessing  does rails provide some way (or should provide this feature)?

Answer (score -1):

No, the purpose is different. The exclamation point means many things and it is more known for being dangerous. There is nothing like alternative for it. It is for the indication of what you are doing is different.

In Ruby, you can write methods whose names end in ! (exclamation point or “bang”).

In standard methods it's often used to indicate a method that causes an object to mutate itself, but not always.

When I say `mutate itself`, that means the object itself gets changed even if you are not assigning it within itself.

A very good example of this is that in Java there are `String` and `StringBuffer/StringBuilder`.

`StringBuffer/StringBuilder` objects are mutable.

The same thing goes here.

So what's **foo.downcase! and foo.downcase**

The `foo.downcase!` will modify the object `foo` itself to downcase without the need of assignment to any other object.

The `foo.downcase` will not modify the object unless it is assigned to some object like doing something like: **bar = foo.downcase**

So in your code use it when you want to do something dangerous, especially when two  methods with the same name exist and one of them is more "dangerous" than the other. "Dangerous" can mean nearly anything though.

Check the [bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist)

Comment: the question is about ! at the front to invert a method response, not methods that end with !.